# How to append files to formData

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload

I am obtaining files and their values in a non-normal way. There isn't an actual input in the form. Therefore, I am trying to append the files to the formData for ajax submission.

Anytime I try to submit the form with the method below, my files aren't uploading. Therefore, the way I am appending the files must be incorrect.

I was told the following from someone, but I can't figure out how to do it:

> You're looping through the array but appending the entire array every
> time through the loop. Use the brackets on the form input name and
> append each file in the array.

Does anyone see what I need to change to get this to work?

Code for the dropzone...before the relevant code below:

```
var dragFileName = '';

var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myDropzone", {
//$('#myDropzone').dropzone ({
//Dropzone.options.myDropzone= {
    url: 'php/quoteSendTest.php',
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    paramName: "file",
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 5,
    maxFilesize: 25,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictFileTooBig: 'File is larger than 25MB',
    init: function() {
        dzClosure = this; // Makes sure that 'this' is understood inside the functions below.

        // for Dropzone to process the queue (instead of default form behavior):
    /*  document.getElementById("submit-all").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
            console.log("Something should be showing for eventListener");
            //e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            dzClosure.processQueue();
        });*/

        this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            /* Maybe display some more file information on your page */
            dragFileName = file.name;
            var dragFileSize = file.size;
            var count = myDropzone.files.length;
            console.log('File added - ' + file.name + ' - Size - ' + file.size);
            console.log(count + " is the length");
            //console.log("FILEname is " + dragFileName);
            setTimeout(function () {
                toggleUploadButton();
            }, 10);
        });

        //send all the form data along with the files:
        /*this.on("sendingmultiple", function(data, xhr, formData) {
            //formData.append("firstname", jQuery("#firstname").val());
            //formData.append("lastname", jQuery("#lastname").val());
        });
        */
    }
});
```

Relevant code:

```
var acceptedFiles = null;
var allAcceptFiles = null;

function toggleUploadButton() {
    acceptedFiles = myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
    allAcceptFiles = acceptedFiles.values();

    for (let fileElements of allAcceptFiles) {
        console.log(fileElements);
    }
}

function submit(){
    var form = document.getElementById("salesforce_submit");
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    fileElements.each(function() {
        formData.append('uploadedFile[]', fileElements);
    });
    alert(formData);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/php/quoteSendTest.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
```

HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo $config['sf_url']; ?>" method="POST" id="salesforce_submit">
    <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
    <div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDropzone">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message dG">Drop files here or click to upload</div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit-all">SEND PROJECT QUOTE</button>
</form>
```

Console.log info from fileElements:

> File {upload: {…}, status: "queued", previewElement:
>
> div.dz-preview.dz-file-preview, previewTemplate:
>
> div.dz-preview.dz-file-preview, _removeLink: a.dz-remove, …} accepted:
>
> true dataURL: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABtUA"
>
> height: 892 lastModified: 1512405192880 lastModifiedDate: Mon Dec 04
>
> 2017 11:33:12 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {} name:
>
> "analytics.PNG" previewElement: div.dz-preview.dz-image-preview
>
> previewTemplate: div.dz-preview.dz-image-preview size: 544438 status:
>
> "queued" type: "image/png" upload: {uuid:
> "6dc946e7-e9db-4b3a-88af-b790de1c2975", progress: 0, total: 544438,
> bytesSent: 0, filename: "analytics.PNG", …} webkitRelativePath: ""
>
> width: 1749
>
> _removeLink: a.dz-remove
>
> **proto**: File

Comment: You want to append each file with a unique index. You want something more like `fileElements.each((index, element) => { formData.append('index', element.files); });`, though I'm not sure where you're actually getting `fileElements` or what type of element the array contains

Comment: @GammaGames The console.log for `fileElements` results in all of the file info. See my edited question.

Comment: could you please include any html to recreate a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It would make it a lot easier to help

Comment: @GammaGames Sure. I don't think the HTML really helps though. I added it to the question. It seems like whenever I try appending anything to the formData or atleast with what I had before and even with your suggestion, that my AJAX submission doesn't run. The only thing that happens is the redirect from the form action.

Comment: I also added more of the javascript to my question. The part added is the dropzone code (drag and drop file upload system) that I am trying to integrate.

Comment: Try `myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().forEach(file => { formData.append("uploadedFile[]", file); });`, it looks like you're trying to iterate through a file object while appending a single file to the form data

Comment: @GammaGames Thanks! That got this working. Could you elaborate more on why that worked and my solution didn't? ....There is one thing that isn't working with your solution. If I'm not sumbitting a file, I get an error. Should I just check for the file count to see if it is  < 0 before appending?

Comment: I think you should wrap whatever is creating the error in a `if(myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().length)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your initial attempt:

```js
function toggleUploadButton() {
    acceptedFiles = myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
    allAcceptFiles = acceptedFiles.values();

    for (let fileElements of allAcceptFiles) {
        console.log(fileElements);
    }
}

var formData = new FormData(form);
fileElements.each(function() {
    formData.append('uploadedFile[]', fileElements);
});
```

You are looping through `allAcceptFiles` and setting each one to `fileElements`. This leaves `fileElements` as a single file, and when try to do the `each` loop later it doesn't act as you'd expect.

I noticed that `myDropzone` must be defined somewhere, since it was working in the first function. Looking at the [dropzone documentation](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods), I saw it had a `getAcceptedFiles` method that you could easily use to loop through and add each file to the form data. The modified loop is below:

```js
var formData = new FormData(form);
myDropzone.getAcceptedFiles().forEach(file => {
    formData.append("uploadedFile[]", file); 
});
```

There are a couple other things that don't seem necessary in the code, but this isn't code review so I'll leave them alone.

Comment: So in a nutshell, adding `file =>` was the differentiator? You are getting individuals files that way and looping through them?

Comment: Before you were attempting to loop through the file (doesn't do anything, since it is not iterable) and add the file to the form. This solution loops through each file in the dropzone, since a file list is iterable. You can read more about iterables [here](https://javascript.info/iterable). The arrow is just an arrow function, just a shorthand for a regular function. You can read more about arrow functions [here](https://javascript.info/function-expressions-arrows).